# How to post data from postman using a static list and also get all data

Tags: java, spring-boot

**I am new to spring boot, I want to post the data(let's say question data) using a static list without using database and repository, but i can't understand how to solve it.**

**This my controller class**

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> createQuestion(@Valid @RequestBody CreateQuestionCommand command) {

    var query = new FindQuestionByIdTemp(command.getId());
    var response = queryGateway.query(query, ResponseTypes.instanceOf(Object.class)).join();
    if (response != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new QuestionCreatedResponse(command.getId(),"This id is already associated with other question"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    try {
        commandGateway.send(command);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new QuestionCreatedResponse(command.getId(), "Question Created successfully!"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        var safeErrorMessage = "Error while processing create question request for id - " + command.getId();
        System.out.println(e.toString());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new QuestionCreatedResponse(command.getId(), safeErrorMessage), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

**CreateQuestionCommandClass**

```
public class CreateQuestionCommand {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;
    private Questions question;
}
```

**Questions Class**

```
public class Questions {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String label;
    private String feedback;

}
```

**This is an AggregateClass**

```
@Aggregate
public class QuestionAggregateClass {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;
    private Questions questions;

    public QuestionAggregateClass() {
    }
    @CommandHandler
    public QuestionAggregateClass(CreateQuestionCommands command) {
        var newQuestion=command.getQuestions();
        newQuestion.setId(command.getId());
        var event = QuestionCreatedEvents.builder()
                .id(command.getId())
                .questions(newQuestion)
                .build();

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(event);
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public  void on(QuestionCreatedEvents event){
        this.id=event.getId();
        this.questions=event.getQuestions();
    }
}
```

## *Here i want to make a static list so that when i post data from postman, it will save in that static list and i am able to getData from here also. But i dont know how to make that fucnction while using lambda expression. I dont want to write dummy data manually here, i want to store it from postman sending post request*

```
public class QuestionDataAsList {
    public static List<Questions> questions;


    public static void save(Questions questions) {
    }
}
```

**And want to make implementation of event here, and want to call static list here.**

```
@Component
public class QuestionEventHandlerImp implements QuestionEventHandler{
    @Override
    public void on(QuestionCreatedEvents event) {
        QuestionDataAsList.save(event.getQuestions());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: My question is that, in a separate class i want to make a static function which stores the list of questions  that stores data when i post from postman in a json format, but when i post the data its not saving in that static function bcz i can't understand what logic i will use. Instead of calling repository, i want to call this QuestionDataAsList class in which static function is implemented  to QuestionEventHandlerImp class.